# How to use fs readFile on a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, fs

So i am using discord.js and i want to read the file for the discord url to be used with tensorflow
Thats how i read a local file and use it but now i want to read a url

```
const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const fs = require('fs')
const imageBuffer = fs.readFile('./data.jpg',  function(err, data) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    const tens = tfnode.node.decodeImage(data)
    func(tens)
});

const func = async(tens) => {

console.log('called')
// Load the model.
const model = await mobilenet.load();
const predictions = await model.classify(tens);

console.log('Predictions: ');
console.log(predictions);
}
```

Comment: `readFile` is for reading files.   URL's are not files,..  You need to do a http request..  For cross compatibility with browser you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch, but any library or even direct http requests in node will work.

Comment: I can fetch the url but will that download the file locall i can just fetch the url then how i would use the fetched response idk mind telling?

Comment: It won't download the file automatically, but why do you need to save the file local, just pass the request data to your `tfnode.node.decodeImage(data)`

Comment: the res body? or what here is the response
https://sourceb.in/OOwlzpEPn2
What do i pass in?

Comment: Here is the res body https://sourceb.in/cX1mplQwFf

Comment: What are you using to fetch the URL data,.  It might make sense posting your request code.

Comment: Node fetch
``` 
let res=  await fetch('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/783627865194758154/7978ng')
   console.log(res.body)
```

Comment: `const buffer = await res.buffer()`

Comment: pass that in? to tfnode

Comment: Yes, that should work.   If you `console.log(buffer)` you should now have an arrayBuffer that `decodeImage` should be able to handle.

Comment: check this out https://sourceb.in/XsYd0OxD9u

Comment: New error
[UNHANDLED REJECTION] Error: Invalid TF_Status: 3
Message: Input to reshape is a tensor with 200704 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 150528